# How to close the JS alerts of Native mobile applications? running tests in BrowserStack using appium

Tags: ios, appium, webdriver-io, browserstack, mobile-app-testing

I am using webdriverIO, appium-service and browserstack-server to run my mobile app automation test in the browserstack. when launching my test app, there is an pop-up/overlay is displaying like below.

[image]

Because of this the test couldn't find the locators under that overlay and the test is failing.

I tried to find the locator of the [X] button But, failed as it is showing the entire overlay as a single locator and if I click it through script the page is getting opened with detailed error description. It would be really helpful if anyone can help/guide me, please!